# get the code of functions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am wondering if we - the Matlab users can get the code of some functions in Matlab (like fft - fast fourier transform, dwt - descrete wavelet transform, and so on.) Just in case we want to edit something to adapt with what we need. 
Is it possible in Matlab? 
and if so, how can we get the code?
Thank you.

Comment: For most Matlab functions you can see the source code by typing "edit <function_name>" at the Matlab prompt.

Comment: Yet most of the basic function are internally implemented and you won't be able to see the source code.

Comment: You _can_ in [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/), and that has the added bonus of not being Matlab! :)

Comment: Btw, [i]fft is implemented using the [fftw](http://www.fftw.org) library.

Comment: You can also get MATLAB-compatible source for many functions from the [Octave sources](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).

Comment: I tried this with `edit gram` and it opens a function called gram but this just calls gram again. Does this mean the source code for the main gram function (to compute the gramian matrix) is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, lots of MATLAB functions are written in MATLAB, so you can see the source. For performance reasons, some things are implemented in native code, or use external libraries. In the case of FFT, MATLAB uses the FFTW library, to which the source is freely available. See also http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fftw.html

Answer (score 6):

Type "edit function.m" (without quotes), where "function" is the name of the function with the code you wish to view.

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_8465386_matlab-function-codes.html#ixzz2wILKOXJI

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in matlab under the current directory menu on the left , the option name is "find Files" which is represented as an icon of binoculars, simply click on it, set the directory to "Enter Matlab Path" and enter the function name to search,

for example, if i want to search function imnoise , i'd type "imnoise.m"
after getting the result of the search, simply double click on the function file and there you can edit whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

To summarize a bit, there a several ways to do it.

E.g., if we want to see the source code of function `imread`:

a) `edit` to edit or create file

```
edit imread; %namely, edit('imread')
edit imread.m; %edit('imread.m')
```

b) `open` to open file in appropriate application

```
open imread; %open file 'imread.m' with matlab editor
```

c) `type` to display contents of file:

```
type imread; %this will display all the contents in command window, which is hard to read
```

**Note** that `funcName stringLiteral` is the *command syntax*, which equals its *function syntax* `funcName('stringLiteral')`. See 
[Command vs. Function Syntax](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html)