# Fmincon Algorithms in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Is there a way to see how algorithms for fmincon: "sqp", "interior-point", "active-set" in Matlab are implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the code of functions in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237836/get-the-code-of-functions-in-matlab)

Comment: I have read this post. But how do I get the script for specific algorithms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two algorithms the relative functions are the following

- active-set: `nlconst`
- trust-region-reflective: `sfminbx` and `sfminle`

To look at the code write `open name_of_the_function`. Unfortunately the functions for the interior-point and sqp algorithms, respectively `barrier` and `sqpLineSearch`, are encrypted and can not be read.

Comment: Thank you. I am having the same trouble as well. : ( I can't what's in barrier and sqpLineSearch. Thank you very much though.